# Firebase Analytics Custom Event Parameter Reporting has (not set)

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

So we've integrated Firebase Analytics and Crashlytics with our mobile app (both Android and iOS) and **it works**. Well it *sort of* works. So we don't have any problems with crashlytics but we have an issue with how our custom events are being reported.

[image: Event parameter results]

If you see the picture above, we have a huge amount of (not set) being recorded. We aren't sending anything custom that isn't being recorded (meaning the big blue box there is all we chose to record) yet we still get (not set) being reported. Is there a way to know what this is or how to remove it? I thought at first it would be `firebase_event_origin` or something similar to that but it isn't as the numbers still keep increasing after we added the said property in parameter reporting.

This is what my parameter reporting looks like for the first image:
[image: Custom event parameter reporting][2]]

For sending data to firebase analytics we just did what was outlined in the docs like:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("image_name", name);
params.putString("full_text", text);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", params);
```

Comment: We have the same issue. Have you figured it out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I did get in touch with Google support though and they said it may be caused when you send a log event that contains null

Comment: We also have this problem, did you manage to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this questions is opened 2,5 years ago, but still if someone else needs info about this issue...

According to other people experiencing the same issue, including myself. It's most likely the value for a custom dimension you set, is not in use anymore (a previously event parameter). Although, there are multiple reasons this could happen.
Take a look at [this case](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article), likely the cause is listed somewhere here.